# CSS | Окончательное изменение свойства класса

Tags: javascript, css

*Задача стоит следующая:* после загрузки страницы плавно показать скрытый объект и оставить его видимым.

---

**На данный момент:** имеется некий объект класса "free". В таблице стилей указываю, что мне необходимо сделать анимацию объекта (изменить прозрачность с 0 на 1 за 2 секунды с задержкой в одну секунду). Делаю это следующим образом:

```
.free{
    -webkit-animation-name: opacity1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity1{
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    25% {opacity: 0.3;}
    50% {opacity:0.5;}
    75% {opacity:0.8;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}
```

Изначально прозрачность элемента равна "1", после чего он  резко исчезает и заново появляется. Совсем не здорово.

Ввести начальное значение руками (opacity:0) не вызывает проблем. Проблему вызывает изменение данного свойства после окончания анимации на 1. Иначе, в этом варианте, объект после анимации принимает значение opacity:0, как и было введено.

---

*Спасибо.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно воспользоватся `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

```css
.free{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: #da3;
    -webkit-animation-name: opacity1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity:0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity1{
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    25% {opacity: 0.3;}
    50% {opacity:0.5;}
    75% {opacity:0.8;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="free"></div>
```